# Pass a context variable through an inclusion tag

Tags: python, django, django-custom-tags

Performing a check to see whether or not a user is attending or not. How do I pass the context variable `is_attending` to the template without getting a syntax error on `'is_attending': context['is_attending']`? The check is basically for styling divs and whatnot. What am I doing wrong?

**template:**

```
{% for event in upcoming %}
    {% registration %}

    {% if is_attending %}
         Registered!
    {% else %}
          Register button
    {% endif %}

    yadda yadda divs...
{% endfor %}
```

**filters.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('events/list.html', takes_context=True)
def registration(context, event):
    request = context['request']
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
    if profile in attendees:
        'is_attending': context['is_attending']
        return is_attending
    else:
        return ''
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`'is_attending': context['is_attending']` is not valid python. Rather, it looks like a partial dictionary. Since `.inclusion_tag()` code is supposed to return a dict, perhaps you meant the following instead:

```
if profile in attendees:
    return {'is_attending': context['is_attending']}
else:
    return {'is_attending': ''}
```

Also note that `takes_context` means you'll *only* take the context as an argument. From the [howto on custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags):

> If you specify takes_context in creating a template tag, the tag will have no required arguments, and the underlying Python function will have one argument -- the template context as of when the tag was called.

Thus your tag should be:

```
 {% registration %}
```

and your full method can take the `event` argument directly from the context:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('events/list.html', takes_context=True)
def registration(context):
    request = context['request']
    event = context['event']
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
    if profile in attendees:
        return {'is_attending': context['is_attending']}
    else:
        return {'is_attending': ''}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I am still unable to pass 'is_attending' due to a template syntax error with `{% registration event %}`. Am I not calling it correctly?

Comment: @Modelesq: updated the answer for you; a `takes_context` inclusion tag method only takes a `context` argument.

Comment: The template is a list of events. Looping through the events, a check has to be made. Since this is filtering through a list of attendees in a specific event. I need to have `{% registration event %}`, otherwise it will not filter `Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)` and perform the check.

Comment: @Modelesq: but when the tag is included, the `context` will hold the current `event` you wanted to pass in already. When you do `{% registration event %}` the `event` value in that statement is *also* looked up in the context. See my version of your `registration` method, it retrieves the event from the context object.

Comment: Missed that. Thank you. But again, I'm still getting that template syntax error. I'll keep playing around with it. I've updated my post, maybe I've missed something, or maybe inclusion tag isn't the way to go?

Comment: @Modelesq: you are still using the `event` variable in the `{% registration %}` tag; you do not need to use that. I did specify that my answer. :-)