# Using django permissions in template tags

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm currently checking permissions in my templates to decide whether or not I want to display a particular link.

This works very well for my base.html that is extending in my normal templates:

**base.html**

```
{% if perms.myapp.can_add %}
    #display link
{% endif %}
```

**my template**

```
{% extends "riskass/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    # do stuff #
{% endblock %}
```

BUT i also use template tags for repetitive items in the template, and the same permission checks doesn't seem to work in them.

Does anybody have an idea of what I might be doing wrong ? Thanks !

**my template**

```
{% extends "riskass/base.html" %}

{% load show_items %}

{% block content %}
    # do stuff #
    {% show_items items_list%}
{% endblock %}
```

**templatetags/show_items.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/show_items.html')
def show_items(items):
    return {'items': items}
```

**myapp/show_items.html**

```
{% for item in items%}

    # display stuff: this works
    ...

    # check permissions: 
     {% if perms.myapp.can_add %}
        #display other link: doesn't do anything
     {% endif %}
```

Comment: As an advice: It is not enough to use `{% load show_item%}`, also you need to use `{% show_item AnObject %}`

Comment: yes yes forgot it in the example but i use that properly; the templatetags works as intended, just not the Auth part in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perms` is part of the template context in which your template "my template" is being rendered.  But your inclusion tag template `myapp/show_item.html` by default has its own context and won't inherit `perms` or any other template variables unless you arrange for that by passing `takes_context=True` in your tag registration, as well as doing just a bit of code to pass some or all of that context into your tag template context.

There's an example of this in the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

It's a bit confusing because the docs seem to imply that you can **either** pass your own arguments to the tag method **or** pass context, but not both.  However that is not the case.  When `takes_context=True` is passed to `@register.inclusion_tag()`, the effect will be that django passes `context` as the first argument to your tag function, followed by any arguments you wish to pass to your tag.  The context being passed is that of the template where your tag is located.. so you can then take what you need from there and pass it to the included template, eg:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('riskass/show_ratings.html', takes_context=True)
def show_ratings(context, ratings):
    return {
        'ratings': ratings,
        'perms': context.get('perms', None)
    }
```

The tag usage would then look like this:

```
{% show_ratings ratings_list %}
```

There is some useful info in this other Stack Overflow question and answer, although it is not exactly the same as your question you might want to take a look:

[Pass a context variable through an inclusion tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079964/pass-a-context-variable-through-an-inclusion-tag)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation; basically i've got to find a way to pass the perms context variable to the inclusion tag. This trick works but it's not ideal... : def show_ratings(items, perms=[]):
    return {
        'items': items,
        'perms': perms
    }. And you call the inclusion tag by doing:  {% show_items items_list perms %}

Comment: i had to use that because my items_list is not always called the same way throughout my app. What do you think ?

Comment: Ok.. well the Django docs imply that you can EITHER pass context OR pass your own arguments, not both.  But I looked at the Django source code: django/template/library.py TagHelperNode.get_resolved_arguments() seems to pass context FIRST and then your own arguments.  So you could have access to both in your inclusion tag function.  But if it turns out to be true that you can only have one or the other, you could pass perms as you are doing or you could just use context and wrap your tag in a {% with %} tag to set the variables you need to change in the context.

Comment: but i was under the impressions reading the docs that the context variable were passed implicitely where you had takes_context = true; so how could you pass both the context AND the list ?

Comment: i'll try that second option of yours; putting my list in the context variables using {% with %} and then getting everything in the inclusion tag

Comment: To answer your first question, I looked at the source mentioned above and there's a place where they prepend `context` to the args list.. so my very quick assumption is that you would get context as the first arg, then your own first arg as the second arg.. etc.

Comment: and i just pass "context" as a "variable" ?  {% show_items context items_list%} ?

Comment: No, use the takes_context=True in your tag declaration

Comment: ok so it works ! in template: {% show_ratings ratings_list %} and in the inclusion tag declaration : def show_ratings(context, ratings): 
    return {
        'ratings': ratings,
        'perms': context['perms']
    }

Comment: Awesome glad I was able to help, I learned something too :)  And thanks Malcolm I will go accept your edits now.